# Order geom_bar y axis by percentage of one particular value in column (position = "fill")

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

how would I go about plotting this where the clusters are reordered in decreasing % of kiwi?

```
df = data.frame()
df = data.frame(matrix(df, nrow=200, ncol=2))
colnames(df) <- c("cluster", "name")
df$cluster <- sample(20, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df$fruit <- sample(c("banana", "apple", "orange", "kiwi", "plum"), size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)

p = ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(cluster), fill = as.factor(fruit)))+
  geom_bar(position = 'fill') + 
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text=element_text(size=20)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  xlab("Cluster")+
  ylab("Fruit percentage") +
  labs( fill = "")
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting the elegeant [solution by @RobertHacken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74447470/12993861) on your former post, you could achieve your desired result using `reorder` by switching to the `mean` instead of using the `sum` and by adding `decreasing=TRUE` if you want to order in decreasing order:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(cluster, fruit == "kiwi", FUN = mean, decreasing = TRUE) , 
                   fill = fruit))+
  geom_bar(position = 'fill') + 
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text=element_text(size=20)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  xlab("Cluster")+
  ylab("Fruit percentage") +
  labs( fill = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect: `reorder(cluster, fruit == "kiwi", FUN = mean, decreasing = TRUE)`

Comment: @TarJae Robert Hacken deserves the honor for teaching my this neat trick in the afternoon. (: